# How to identify a section of a PDF in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, loops, pdf, itext, sections

I was wondering if it was possible to retrieve text in a PDF by its section (Header, Body, Footer,etc) I am able to get the text and their specific coordinates but I don't want to define my own x and y coordinates for the sections. I was wondering if there was a more dynamic way of approaching this.
Maybe looping through XrefObjects. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: A generic PDF contains no explicit information on what is header, footer, body, it only knows text and graphics drawn at certain coordinates, You can try and analyze implicit information given e.g. via fonts, font sizes, alignment, gaps, etc. pp. But this is a project by itself.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your PDF files have been created by a very consistent source and you don't have to deal with "PDF files in general", the answer to your question is:

- no, you can't do this in an easy way
- but you could come up with a dynamic approach (perhaps).

PDF doesn't have any provision to structure its content such as you would have in XML, HTML, Word etc... The concept of a header, body, footer doesn't exist. Even the concept of a paragraph, line or word don't exist. PDF is only interested in making sure specific characters (glyphs) are shown in specific locations.

So, if you want to come up with a dynamic approach, you would have to write an algorithm that analyses text position of the all the text on the page, correlates that to other properties of that text (such as font used, font size, color, style...) and from that analysis makes a guesstimate on what is the header, body and footer.